# Deploy All Project Dependencies to a Remote Repository

Tags: java, maven, archiva

We hava a new project friend and we want to install the project to his enviroment. But there are too many dependencies that not exists in the maven repository. So maven became useless. We installed an archiva server to install our artifacts there, but we dont want to deploy all that dependencies one by one(not only project jar self, all the dependencies). Is there an automated solution for this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially if you tweak your projects **pom.xml** and add:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>localrepo</outputDirectory>
                        <useRepositoryLayout>true</useRepositoryLayout>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and run **mvn package** this should create a copy of your dependencies in repository directory format inside the *localrepo* directory (*I tried using the command line options to **dependency:copy-dependencies** but it wouldn't work for me*). Now comment out the above from your **pom.xml** as you probably don't need it anymore.

I've never used Archiva but I imagine at this point you could install the *localrepo* repository files onto a local web server and configure your Archiva server to mirror it.

Alternatively, if you wanted to produce a minimal effort install for your end user (and distribution size wasn't an issue) you could include this *localrepo* directory in your distribution and provide maven with a reference to it by adding the following to your **pom.xml**:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-repo</id>
        <name>local-repo</name>
        <url>file://${basedir}/localrepo</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This local repository technique is very useful when distributing home grown and 3rd party jar files that are not in public Maven repositories.  You can always remove the libraries that are in public repositories.

I find nothing discourages new users from Maven quicker than my trying to explain all that **mvn install:install-file** palaver that is usually necessary to install 3rd party jars (however enthusiastic I may be about Maven).